# wc / cat command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I'm trying to run some simple bash script which uses `wc` and `cat` commands. The script fails with this:

```
wc: command not found
```

or this (after I commented string which uses wc):

```
cat: command not found
```

I have no idea what's going on.
A similar script which contains exactly the same fragments of code works just perfect. 
Both scripts are used in the same conditions.
Besides,

```
machine:~ user$ which wc
/usr/bin/wc
```

and

```
machine:~ user$ which cat
/bin/cat
```

Comment: Are you using the full absolute path to wc and cat in the script?  The environment that the script is running doesn't have the contents of your PATH variable for your login shell.   If that's not it, please show use how you are using these in the script.

Comment: God dammit! I've used PATH as a name of my local variable, lol
Great hint Tyson, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tyson, the `PATH` variable holds the answer.

I just wanted to point out that using full paths in your scripts is usually considered a good practice.  For example, instead of calling `wc` you might want to call `/usr/bin/wc`.  Besides resolving the above problem, it's more secure, as you prevent running an application that someone might have put in your PATH using the same name... I can't remember the name of those attacks, but you get the idea **=)**